# PHP xml working with ba.com API

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I retrieve data from ba.com API using Flight Offer Market Affliates in xml format:

```
$url="https://api.ba.com/rest-v1/v1/flightOfferMktAffiliates;departureDateTimeOutbound=".$Fwk->returnTrueDate($_POST['departureDate']).
                    ";locationCodeOriginOutbound=".$_POST['departureMenu'].
                    ";locationCodeDestinationOutbound=".$_POST['destination'].
                    ";departureDateTimeInbound=".$Fwk->returnTrueDate($_POST['returnDate']).
                    ";locationCodeOriginInbound=".$_POST['destination'].
                    ";locationCodeDestinationInbound=".$_POST['departureMenu'].
                    ";cabin=Economy".
                    ";ADT=".$_POST['adults'].
                    ";CHD=".$_POST['children'].
                    ";INF=0".
                    ";format=.xml";
            $response = curl_get( $url );
            $xml = simplexml_load_string( $response );
```

I receive something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <Success xmlns:a="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:ns="http://www.ba.com/wsdl/availabilitymanagerv1" xmlns:tns="http://www.ba.com/schema/availabilitymanager/tGetAvailabilityV2"/>
    <PricedItineraries>
        <PricedItinerary SequenceNumber="1">
            <AirItinerary>
                <OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <OriginDestinationOption>
                        <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2015-05-15T11:05:00" DepartureDateTime="2015-05-15T08:25:00" FlightNumber="117" ResBookDesigCode="O">
                            <DepartureAirport LocationCode="LHR" Terminal="5"/>
                            <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="JFK"/>
                            <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="British Airways"/>
                            <Equipment AirEquipType="744"/>
                            <MarketingAirline Code="BA"/>
                            <TPA_Extensions>
                                <CabinInfo CabinCode="M" CabinName="World Traveller"/>
                            </TPA_Extensions>
                        </FlightSegment>
                    </OriginDestinationOption>
                    <OriginDestinationOption>
                        <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2015-06-15T19:15:00" DepartureDateTime="2015-06-15T07:15:00" FlightNumber="180" ResBookDesigCode="O">
                            <DepartureAirport LocationCode="JFK" Terminal="7"/>
                            <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="LHR"/>
                            <OperatingAirline CompanyShortName="British Airways"/>
                            <Equipment AirEquipType="744"/>
                            <MarketingAirline Code="BA"/>
                            <TPA_Extensions>
                                <CabinInfo CabinCode="M" CabinName="World Traveller"/>
                            </TPA_Extensions>
                        </FlightSegment>
                    </OriginDestinationOption>
                </OriginDestinationOptions>
            </AirItinerary>
...
```

And this is as far as I got with understanding the above xml:

```
foreach($xml->PricedItineraries->PricedItinerary as $item)
            {
                echo "here";
            }
```

The above returns a lot of "here" messages, meaning I can loop. But after trying all sorts of echo with $item, I couldn't display a thing. Can anyone show me how I can at least get to  and DepartureAirport and read variables from them like ArrivalDateTime and LocationCode.

**EDIT**

Got it working. See answer.

Comment: start your loop from the parent batches, then work your way over there if you need another foreach. i'm guessing there's a lot of `<PricedItinerary>` batches, start from there

Comment: do `$item->asXML('php://output');` and take care you view that output as plain text (e.g. on the commandline or when you output to browser, use the text/plain content-type or a content type that even offers XML syntax highlighting in your browser, check your browsers technical support manual for that).

Comment: There is a [pretty decent guide to basic usage of SimpleXML in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). Play around with those examples and get the feel of it, and should be obvious how to apply the same techniques to your XML.

Comment: I will attempt the above suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @eltaro: Add your solution as the answer below. Be similar extensive with the answer description as well as with the code as you've been in your quesiton. You can mark the question as answered then later.

Comment: In a few hours, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to xml code in the question, this nested foreach will create a table layout and pull data from xml into it.

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Departure date</label></td>
                <td><label>Operator</label></td>
                <td><label>Airport</label></td>
                <td><label>Terminal</label></td>
                <td><label>Flight number</label></td>
                <td><label>Return date</label></td>
                <td><label>Operator</label></td>
                <td><label>Airport</label></td>
                <td><label>Terminal</label></td>
                <td><label>Flight number</label></td>
                <td><label>Cost<label></td>
            </tr>


        $i=0;
        $c=0;
        foreach($xml->PricedItineraries->PricedItinerary as $pricedItinerary)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($pricedItinerary->AirItinerary->OriginDestinationOptions->OriginDestinationOption as $origin)
            {
            //each cycle through this foreach fills one half of a given row.
                echo "<td id='cell_".$i.",".$c."'>".$origin->FlightSegment->attributes()->DepartureDateTime."</td>";$c++; //Such heresy, much reference
                echo "<td id='cell_".$i.",".$c."'>".$origin->FlightSegment->OperatingAirline->attributes()->CompanyShortName."</td>";$c++;
                echo "<td id='cell_".$i.",".$c."'>".$origin->FlightSegment->DepartureAirport->attributes()->LocationCode."</td>";$c++;
                echo "<td id='cell_".$i.",".$c."'>".$origin->FlightSegment->DepartureAirport->attributes()->Terminal."</td>";$c++;
                echo "<td id='cell_".$i.",".$c."'>".$origin->FlightSegment->attributes()->FlightNumber."</td>";$c++;
            }
            echo "<td id='cell_".$i.",".$c."'>£".$pricedItinerary->AirItineraryPricingInfo->ItinTotalFare->TotalFare->attributes()->Amount."</td>";
            $c=0;//reset counter to 0 to avoid generating numbers too large
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
        }
```

There are two FlightSegment arrays inside the given xml, one containing a flight to destination and another - a return flight. To create one row of data that contains both FlightSegments, you need another foreach inside the first that will take OriginDestinationOption as argument. After it loops twice, the main foreach will step into another PricedItinerary (or SequenceNumber if you like).

The `$i` and `$c` are used to give each generated cell a unique id. `$i` iterates with outer loop, `$c` iterates with every `<td>` element and is reset at the end of each row.